# Excel Formula: An Array formula containing VLOOKUP, SMALL, IF, OR

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am trying to create a formula that considers the data from three columns Y, H and V on my tab titled 'Data', returning the smallest value in A that meets that condition, once found Vlookup that smallest value and return the value from B. Below is what I have so far, and it is working until I try to add in my last condition.

I am looking to change the IF(Data!V:V="4") function with an OR function, I would like to turn the v:v="4" into " V:V="4" or V:V="5" ", when I tried to include an OR function the formula started ignoring the V:V condition and starts returning only if the Y and H conditions are met.

Below is the working formula with one V:V condition working without the OR function. Thank you in advance for any help.

=VLOOKUP((SMALL(IF(Data!Y:Y="3",IF(Data!H:H=3,IF(Data!V:V="4",Data!A:A))),1)),Data!A:B,2,0)

I may not have been too clear, let's see if this example complicates things further. Rows 3 and 5 both conform to what I want (H=3, Y=3, V=4or5), but I want to retun B=111 because 3 is the smallest number that conforms.

```
(A)     (B)     (H)     (Y)     (V)
-----------------------------------
1       108     3       3       3
2       109     3       2       4
3       111     3       3       4
4       102     1       3       5
5       101     3       3       5
```

Comment: Can you post some samples where you are facing the issue, I tried it and don't see any difference between using an "IF" or and "OR" function.

Comment: An OR function won't work within an array formula because it simplifies the array down to a single value, so if you have and data!V:V that matches 4 or 5 in any of the rows it will all return true.  You could use another if statement if the first V:V returns false.

Comment: I hope I didn't waste too much of your time, but I think I have figured out a solution, I am going to format my columns to numbers since the largest value of V:V is 5, I changed by last IF to ">=3" instead of 4 and 5.

Comment: If you don’t want to waste our time, then please put a little more of your time into writing a clear question.
Your first paragraph and your formula refer to the three data columns in the order `Y`, `H`, `V`.
Then the last paragraph and the sample data list them in the order `H`, `Y`, `V`.
Not only are these different orders, but neither of them is alphabetic.
This makes the whole question harder to parse.
Also, the explanation “I want H=3, Y=3, V=4or5” should have appeared before the formula.
And what was the meaning of the hyphens (minus signs) after the numbers in your initial example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to use your basic formula and change it to work as an array function.

The function can go on one line I just seperated the if statement to draw attention to it

```
=VLOOKUP((SMALL(IF(
(Data!Y:Y="3")*(Data!H:H=3)*((Data!V:V="4")+(Data!V:V="5")),
Data!A:A),1)),Data!A:B,2,0)
```

In an if statement 1 is treated as TRUE and 0 is treated as FALSE so a * works like **and** and + works like **OR**

The if statement basically says if Y:Y=3 and H:H=3 and (V:V=4 or V:V=5) then return A:A

Still an array formula still needs to be entered with **CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER**

Comment: I tried your suggestion and received and error for too few arguments.

Comment: I forgot to remove the extra brackets when I updated your formula (I removed a couple if statements)

Comment: Thank you! I had spent too long trying ot work this out. I read somewhere the having too many array's is inefficient (I'm finding that) and will slow down my workbook, is a pivot table the better solution?

Comment: array formulas can slow down the workbook significantly depending on how big the arrays are.  A pivot table may work depending on how the rest of your data looks and what exactly your trying to get out of it.  It would be less dynamic then the formula if the data is constantly changing/updating.